# How to navigate clicking row to another UITableView?

Tags: uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to show detailed UItable view when clicking on row. I used

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
// AnotherViewController *anotherViewController = [[AnotherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherView" bundle:nil];
photoListViewController  = [[PhotoListViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PhotoListViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:photoListViewController animated:YES];
[photoListViewController release];



// [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController];
// [anotherViewController release];
}
```

This PhotoListViewController is an empty UITableViewController. As I know UITableViewCOntroller has a navigation controller implemented and I don`t have to create navigation controller. But When I clicked on row it does not navigate to second view.AM I have to make some connection on nib file?I only created this PhotoListViewController in File->New->UIViewCOntroller and selected UITableView.

**EDIT : SOLVED**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem.I should use UINAvigation object.I thought that UITable has it but there was no ))